# replace an API during tests in the Jest environment for React Native for axios AxiosInstance

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, mocking, testing-library

I have a customized Axios instance with multiple rules, including interceptors, which I don't want to test directly. I'm looking to use MSW (Mock Service Worker) to mock API responses and replace my complex Axios instance with a simplified one for testing purposes.

```
import { http, HttpResponse } from 'msw';
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
import axios from 'axios';
import { myApi } from '~/services/api';

const mockedApi = axios.create({ baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000' });

const server = setupServer(
  http.get('http://localhost:3000/test', () => {
    return HttpResponse.json({ id: '1' });
  }),
);
jest.mock('~/services/api', () => {
  return {
    myApi: mockedApi,
  };
});

describe('useVerifyIfPdvStillAvalaible Hook', () => {
  beforeAll(() => server.listen());
  afterEach(() => server.resetHandlers());
  afterAll(() => server.close());

  it('its thorw message: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')', async () => {
    const response = await beepayApi.get('/test');
    
  });
});
```